# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

Пытаюсь запустить программу, которая буквально 10 минут назад работала без проблем, а сейчас выдает ошибку об отсутствии атрибута 'name_scope'. В чем может быть проблема? никаких новых модулей за это время не устанавливала, ничего в них не меняла.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import utils

train_imgs=[]
a=[]
b=[]
with open('train.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        for i in line[0]:
            i=int(i)
            a.append(i)        
train_labels=utils.to_categorical(a, 10)
class_names = ["Злость", "Отвращение", "Страх", "Радость", "Грусть", "Удивление", "Нейтральная эмоция" ]
```

Ошибка: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'`

Comment: Это тот код? В этом коде не используется ни аттрибут name_scope, ни сам модуль tensorflow.

Comment: это значит, что у модуля 'tensorflow' нет атрибута 'name_scope'

Comment: О том и речь, что ничего из этого в коде не использовано. Это то и вводит в ступор

Comment: Я убрала импорт модулей keras и ошибка ушла. Только вопрос не исчерпан, эти модули мне нужны для дальнейшей работы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось исправить ошибку, удалив tensorflow и переустановив таким способом:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.14.0
```